# Sticky not sticking

Tags: html, css, sticky

I can't work out why this isn't sticking. The exact CSS works on other pages I've used it on.

```css
 body {
   min-height: 200vh;
 }
.link {
  background-color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.link li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="link">
  <li><a href="https://www." style="color:black;">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://services." style="color:black;">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://contact." style="color:black;">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've removed the domain as the client doesn't yet want the site publicised at all

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. Move your code to a code snippet (`Ctrl + M`  or the `<>` Button). Make sure it is a [repro]. Your code currently does not indicate why it should not work. My educated guess is, that you nested your ul (which should be a `<menu>` btw.) inside another element. Note that sticky elements are remain to be a part of their parent and will leave the screen as soon as the parent element does.

Comment: Thanks for your response tachoshy, I do apologies about formatting the question incorrectly. I've spent far too long at the computer trying to fathom this to no avail. I guess just more playing. My understanding of programming is fairly small to be honest hence hwy I used ul instead.

Comment: Seems to work in the snippet. Is your `.link` menu inside a relative element?

Comment: `margin: 10;` is not valid. You'd need to provide a unit (e.g. `%`, `px`, `em`, `rem`, `vh`, etc) unless the value is `0`. Try changing it to `margin: 10px`.

Comment: Found the problem, I accidentally put the closing center tag after the UL. This meant it was confined to a parent element from what I can tell. Thanks guys! Also, I have just changed the margin. Cheers